# Storing 'How many times user receive notification' on database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm developing this function "Send notification to all users * times" using Java Spring and MySQL

This is a database structure that I came up with

TABLE: NOTIFICATION

```
╔════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════╦══════════════════════╦══╗
║ ID ║       TITLE        ║      CONTENT       ║   RECEIVE_CRITERIA   ║  ║
╠════╬════════════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══╣
║  1 ║ Welcome to our app ║ NULL               ║ Just for demonstrate ║  ║
║  2 ║ Hi                 ║ Welcome to our app ║ Just for demonstrate ║  ║
╚════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════╩══════════════════════╩══╝
```

TABLE: NOTIFICATION_SETTING

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════╗
║ NOTI_ID ║ MAX_SEND_TIME ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║       1 ║             3 ║
║       2 ║             5 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════════╝
```

TABLE: NOTIFICATION_STATISTIC

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════╦════════════════╦══╗
║ ID ║ USER_ID ║ NOTI_ID ║ NUM_OF_RECEIVE ║  ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬════════════════╬══╣
║  1 ║      23 ║       1 ║           2    ║  ║
║  2 ║      32 ║       1 ║           1    ║  ║
║  3 ║      23 ║       2 ║           3    ║  ║
║  4 ║      32 ║       2 ║           5    ║  ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════╩════════════════╩══╝
```

There is a problem I'm facing:

1. When there is new notification program created (mean this notification preparing to send first time), I query for an eligible list of user can receive that notification, then I loop through each and insert new record into NOTIFICATION_STATISTIC. The list I receive can be up to 20,000 records.

I feel that loop through so many records and perform an insertion could be a problem to our server but I don't know how to improve it. So I want to ask if there is any better solution that can solve my problem?

**(Please ignore this one, the same problem with 1)**
2. Each time I resend that notification, I query for a new user list that NOT EXIST IN NOTIFICATION_STATISTIC and do the same loop like step 1. The list I receive here can be up to 1000 records.

Thank you for reading.

EDIT: edit 1) and 2) to make question more understandable

Comment: Sorry about a wrong format! I have to go home now, after back home I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 from your question says: You have all users in an array "users".
Step 2: In this step you perform insertions in NOTIFICATION_STATISTIC table and you also confirm if there is an statistics for that user and notification combination for which you want to minimize querying load.

Before step 2, get all notifications statistics (as array e.g. "statistics") from NOTIFICATION_STATISTIC table where NOTI_ID is the current notification ID for which you have to insert let's say 20,000 records.

Now, the actual step 2 which inserts the rows in NOTIFICATION_STATISTIC, just check the "statistics" array for the current user id from the loop, if it's there, do not insert, if the user id is not there in the array "statistics", only then insert.

Sample code (just logic, not written for Java):

```
variable notitfication_id = 3; 
array users; // all list of users
statistics = "SELECT USER_ID FROM NOTIFICATION_STATISTIC WHERE NOTI_ID = notitfication_id"; // SQL query;
foreach (users as user) {
    if (!statistics contain user.id OR user.id IS NOT IN the array statistics) {
        INSERT INTO NOTIFICATION_STATISTIC VALUES ('', user.id, notitfication_id, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for making you misunderstood my question. 1) and 2) is not 2 steps. It's 2 problems I'm facing. I will edit my question for more understandable